# Does Call of Duty: United Offensive need CoD 2?

Tags: call-of-duty-united-offensive, call-of-duty-2

When installing *Call of Duty: United Offensive*, does the game require Call of Duty 2?

I mean, is the expansion standalone or dependent on COD2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_of_Duty:_United_Offensive) and Google, you need Call of Duty 1 to run this, since it is an expansion pack of the **first** game, not the second.

> Call of Duty: United Offensive is a 2004 expansion pack for the first-person shooter video game Call of Duty.

Comment: lol nice edit... it should have said on Steam, too, but the question's author may have disc copy

Comment: @Tkdestroyer2 Yeah I do have a disc copy.